# Is it possible to nest forms in Wicket that are independent of each other?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

Is it possible to nest forms in Wicket that are independent of each other? I want to have a form with a submit button and a cancel button. Both buttons should direct the user to the same page (let's call it Foo). The submit button should send some info to the server first; the cancel button should do nothing.

Here's a really simplified version of my existing code:

```
Form form = new Form() {
    public void onSubmit()
    {
        PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
        params.put("DocumentID", docID);
        setResponsePage(Foo.class, params);
    }
};

DropDownChoice<String> ddc = new DropDownChoice<String>("name", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "nameSelection"), names);
ddc.setRequired(true);

final Button submitButton = new Button("Submit") {
    public void onSubmit() { doSubmitStuff(true); }
};

final Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel") {
    public void onSubmit() { doSubmitStuff(false); }
};

form.add(ddc);
form.add(submitButton);
form.add(cancelButton);
form.add(new FeedbackPanel("validationMessages"));
```

The problem is, I just added a validator, and it fires even if I press the cancel button, since the cancel button is attached to the same form as everything else. This could be avoided if the cancel button were in a separate form. As far as I know, I can't create a separate form because — due to the structure of the HTML — the separate form would be under the existing form in the component hierarchy.

Can I make the forms separate somehow in spite of the hierarchy? Or is there some other solution I can use?

EDIT:
In response to Don Roby's comment, this is a bit closer to what my code looked like back when I was trying `setDefaultFormProcessing()`:

```
    Form<Object> theForm = new Form<Object>("theForm") {
        public void onSubmit()
        {
            PageParameters params = new PageParameters();
            params.put("DocumentID", docID);
            setResponsePage(Foo.class, params);
        }
    };

    final CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox("checkbox", new PropertyModel<Boolean>(this, "something"));
    checkbox.add(new PermissionsValidator());
    theForm.add(checkbox);

    final Button saveButton = new Button("Save") {
        public void onSubmit()
        { someMethod(true); }
    };
    final Button cancelButton = new Button("Cancel") {
        public void onSubmit()
        { someMethod(false); }
    };

    cancelButton.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
    theForm.add(saveButton);
    theForm.add(cancelButton);
    theForm.add(new FeedbackPanel("validationMessages"));
```

Comment: You seem to have two forms (theForm and configureRuleForm) in the new sample code.  Is this an editing accident or are there really two forms?

Comment: @Don, sorry, editing accident; it's fixed now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an even simpler solution: call the `setDefaultFormProcessing` method on the cancel button with `false` as a parameter:

```
cancelButton.setDefaultFormProcessing(false);
```

This way, clicking the cancel button will bypass the form validation (and model updating), directly calling the `onSubmit` function.

Comment: -1, this was one of the first things I tried, but the validation kept on firing.

Comment: @Lord Torgamus - Sorry this didn't seem to work for you, but it is indeed the normal way to skip validation on a submit button.

Comment: Okay, I've tried this again, and it seems to work now. There must have been some separate error preventing the page from working before. Vote changed from -1 to +1. (Sorry for editing, but I couldn't change my vote otherwise.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to "nest" forms in wicket.

See [this wiki entry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Nested+Forms) 
 for some notes on how it works and [this wiki entry](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Conditional+Validation) for how it interacts with validation.

But for what you're after, the answer from Jawher should have worked and is much simpler.

Look at this [example code](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/compref/wicket/bookmarkable/org.apache.wicket.examples.compref.ButtonPage) for hints on getting that working.

I'm wondering if you've simplified your code too far in this posting.  Can you produce a sample small enough to post that definitely has the problem?